# Sonarlint for Eclipse - Unable to load plugin bundleentry error

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I am getting below exception when tried to scan the project in Eclipse IDE for Java developers Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) Build id: 20211202-1639

```
Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 7.2.0.42510
Started security hotspot handler on port 64120
SonarLint analysis of project FrontEndIssuesReporterV2 (22 files processed)...
Starting standalone SonarLint engine 7.2.0.42510...
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://427.fwk1108469971/plugins/sonar-python-plugin-3.9.0.9230.jar
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://427.fwk1108469971/plugins/sonar-python-plugin-3.9.0.9230.jar
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.toPath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.withEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:104)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:115)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:62)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:1)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.run(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:393)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:201)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:157)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractSonarProjectJob.run(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to upgrade SonarLint for Eclipse plugin to **7.2.1**

References in SonarSouce community:

- [Error message Unable to load plugin bundleentry at opening a file in eclipse](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-message-unable-to-load-plugin-bundleentry-at-opening-a-file-in-eclipse/57107)
- [SonarLint for Eclipse 7.2.0.42510 fails](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-for-eclipse-7-2-0-42510-fails/57121)

If your Eclipse installation path contains some space (ex: `C:\Program files\`), the solution is to downgrade SonarLint for Eclipse plugin to **7.1** or upgrade to **7.3**:

- [Unable to load plugin …/sonar-secrets-plugin-1.1.0.36766.jar when Eclipse is installed in a directory with a whitespace](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unable-to-load-plugin-sonar-secrets-plugin-1-1-0-36766-jar-when-eclipse-is-installed-in-a-directory-with-a-whitespace/57343)
- [SLE-501](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-501)